# about 'strcpy' function using

Tags: c, arrays, strcpy

```
char input[32];
char name[32];
char discountUser[32];//not sure to using about arrays.
char notDiscountUser[32];//not sure to using about arrays.
int i,j;
int len;
fgets(input,32,stdin);
sscanf(input,"%s",name);
len = strlen(name);
for(i=0,j=0; i < len; i++)
{
if(isdigit(name[i]))
{
    digits[j] = name[i];

    if (digits[j] > 48)
    {
        strcpy(discountUser[i],name); //i want to stored the name at i index
        printf("you have discount code\n");
    }
    else if (digits[j] <= 48)
    {
        strcpy(notDiscountUser[i],name); //i want to stored the name at i index
        printf("you don't have discount code\n");
    }
    j++ ;
}
}
```

I need to separate user who have discountcode or not 
 by enter 3charofname and 1 digit  eg. cat2
  if digit more than 0 so, the user  have discount
  if digit is 0 so, they not have discount
example i have cat0 bee1 ear2 eye0
when i print 
notdiscount : cat0 , eye0
discount : bee1 , ear2

i check digit by isdigit and i have problem with copy username by strcpy .
Thanks for help .  :]

Comment: What is the need to put ** before strcpy ?

Comment: BTW char input[32] is an array, char discountUser[32][32] is a matrix. so 32 columns of 32 rows

Comment: What is digits[j] ? I think you also need to read how strcpy is working : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2D arrays as:

```
char discountUser[N][32];  
char notDiscountUser[N][32];
```

where `N` is max number of users, you can `#define` it to some value.

What you are trying to do is:

```
char discountUser[32];
```

This is a string, if you use `char discountUser[i]` you are referring to the **`char`** (A single character, not a string) at index `i` in the string `discountUser`.

Now, `strcpy` expects a **string** as input to both of its arguments, therefore you cannot pass `discountuser[i]` as its input.

When you declare a 2D array as I told above, `discountuser[i]` will refer to a **`string`** (actually `dicountuser[i]` will act as `char` pointer), so now you are allowed to pass it as argument to `strcpy`.